# How to get mail from contact us form in bootstrap/html

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, contact-form, mailto

As i have implemented this code in my web application web form on Asp.net
  
http://azuresolutionz.com/ContactUs.html Kindly check the link for the detailed issue.

When i click to send button i do not get the form detail in my inbox. 
and the js is also not working.

Comment: Don't you need a backend's help like PHP, Java, RoR to send the mailer. Which are you using ? I do not see any.

Comment: What server side processing are you using? is it a PHP mail sender? where is the code? What have you tried? The page you have attached here doesn't look like it has any onclick submit events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh I see, you have implemented mail in a very weird way here.

**Firstly very important** - I see the error  message "$ is not defined" in your console. But I see the jquery file in your Resource folder, which only means you have called the `jquery-2.1.4.min.js` in the wrong order.

**You first need to call the `jquery-2.1.4.min.js` file before all the other js files like bootstrap.min.js and your ContactUs.js**. You can give it a try after you do this change. This should remove most of your js errors.

That being cleared now you can check the rest of the information I provided to get a better understanding on how your mail system works.

- You have not used any server side technologies but directly fetching the values from the fields and on-click of the send button you are retrieving all the form inputs data and using `mail:to`.
- `mail:to` opens a mail(with the data) on the user's default mail client to send the mail.
- So just expect(after clicking "Send" button) for the data to populate on your default Email Client like Outlook(Windows) or Mail(MAC).
- Here on your Email Client you need to send the mail like how you would send any normal mail to send and receive ofcourse.

Alternatively if you do not want `mailto`, then you have to use any server side mailer implementation making use of PHP or Java or C# etc.

**Updated as per @Shahzeb's request:**

After creating the **ContactUs.ascx** files,

Firstly you need to make your input text fields as `asp:TextBox` and add an `ID` attribute to it, as this is how we can get the value of the corresponding fields on the code behind page. This would look something like

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" />
```

Do this for all your fields.

Then Add this to your **ContactUs.ascx.cs** file (which is the code behind page of ContactUs.ascx).

Note: It has `using System.Net.Mail;` added.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Net.Mail;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage(txtFirstName.Text, txtLastName.Text, txtEmail.Text, txtPhone.Text);
            SmtpClient emailClient = new SmtpClient(txtSMTPServer.Text);
            emailClient.Send(message);
            litStatus.Text = "Message Sent";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            litStatus.Text=ex.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As i have corrected jquery-2.1.4.min.js , now i am getting this error TypeError: $(...).bootstrapValidator is not a function  , From where i can get bootstrapvalidator function on.

Comment: Here is the [Github link](https://github.com/nghuuphuoc/bootstrapvalidator/blob/master/src/js/bootstrapValidator.js) to the file you need. You can just download only this file from the given link. Also please note this file has to be included after `bootstrap.min.js`. Just FYI, this library is no longer supported and they started another library named [formValidation](http://formvalidation.io/) instead.

Comment: if i dont want to use any server side mailto , and i want direct mail on my email so what should i do ? i dont want to create or attach database

Comment: you have done it right then...Your mail seems to be working fine. Please observe when you click "Send" button, the mail appears along with the form data in your default Mail client ie. Outlook(Windows) or Mail(MAC).

Comment: Sir i do not want that the default mail software open at the client side , i want the information direct on my mail box when the client click send button

Comment: Then you have only one solution - Web Form Builder, This is one of the web form I have used long back - [Simple Form](https://getsimpleform.com/). You first need to generate an API token and setup the environment. Then you can just create your own form and use it. Here a 3rd party provides you with the server side processing, so all you have to worry about is the setup. The link I gave you is very self explanatory. Let me know if you face any doubts I will give you step by step guide on how to use it.

Comment: but sir if i want to build my own form , that would be secure enough .

Comment: Or sir you can guide me how can i build server side , so that i can go through with it easily and secure.

Comment: Ofcourse I will guide you. You are using c# right. First of all tel me, The "ContactUs" page you are using, is it a **.ascx** file ? Can you make it as one ?

Comment: it is html page , so 1st i have to convert it in .ascx file ?

Comment: Yes it would be much better since we could use it to send mail using C# using SMTP client. You know how to do that right ? Your form will remain the same just fyi.

Comment: Yeah I just need to take add new item as .ascx and put my contact us form , after that what I have to do from where I have to implement code for it

Comment: Right and now you just need to add the code I updated in my answer to your **.ascx.cs** file.

Comment: Yes i'm updating the code. Can you join this [chat here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104964/discussion-problem-solving) soon to discuss further.

Comment: cant access to the chat.

Comment: i dont have 20 reputation so cant access to chat

Comment: add me on skype , shazoo.khan

Comment: nikhil sorry i was busy with other things , now lets get back to it if you dont mind. can u guide me when your online?